# CPU Throttling Issues with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cpu, throttling

I am working on an application in WPF using Vlc.DotNet. I was having an issue with the video playing back with a terrible frame rate on my laptop.

After some research I identified that the issue is related to the CPU throttling down. If the laptop power profile is in BatterySaver mode it has the issue. If I switch it to performance, everything works fine. It seems to me like in BatterySaver mode it allows the processor to throttle down, and for some reason doesn't throttle back up correctly when the application needs it to. Is there anyway I can fix this issue?

I tried setting the priority with the code below and it didn't seem to make a difference.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
```

Vlc.DotNet updates and ImageSource with the next rendered image. I have this source bound to an Image on the GUI that displays it. I used the WPF Performance Kit and can see what is happening, but not why. As soon as it starts playing, AKA updating the image on the GUI at 30fps, the frame rate of the entire application drops down to around 5fps.

Comment: This issue seems to be related with the power management software for your laptop.

Comment: Did you tried to play the same video in WMP and see what happens?

Comment: What makes you sure it is the CPU speed?  On laptops with hybrid video systems, changing power profile may shut down the discrete graphics card and start using the iGPU instead -- that can explain your problems much more easily than CPU power saving.  What video card(s) are in your machine?

Comment: You are correct the laptop does have 2 graphics systems. The onboard Intel and an Nvidia chip. I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue though. It is possible to set what chip you want an application to run on. I tried switching it to the Nvidia chip and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Although you might be correct, it might not be CPU related. I just tried changing the min cpu % in the settings to 100% and the issue still existed. I didn't see any other settings that looked like they might be the cause.

Comment: It does play fine in WMP and VLC. It seems like the issue is that WPF cannot maintain a good FPS for the GUI for some reason.

Comment: I've a strong suspicion that whatever you did to force use of the nVidia dGPU didn't actually work.

Comment: Which OS you're using? WMP and VLC will leverage the [Multimedia Class Scheduler service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). May be that's the reason it can perform better? You can regiser for your application also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching to [software rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid the bottleneck of CPU power downs?  I know WPF uses a separate thread for rendering and I'm not sure if you can even access it from Process.Threads.  What I've done in the past is attach to the [power mode changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and switched the mode dynamically [like this](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/enable-software-rendering-in-wpf-programmatically/) so power mode changes don't switch to hardware rendering.  Not sure if this will work as I don't what your specific bottleneck is, but hopefully this points you in a good direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I tried switching to software rendering and it didn't seem to make a difference.